# Preventing incorrect URL escaping in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

How do you prevent IE8 from escaping "#" as "%23" in URLs?

I'm using Javascript to dynamically set the window.location.href with URLs that sometimes contain "#" for anchor names (e.g. "/some/path/#anchorname")

Firefox/Safari/Chrome interpret this perfectly. Naturally, IE routinely replaces "#" with "%23", resulting in a completely incorrect URL (e.g. "/some/path/%23anchorname").

Answer (score 0):

[History.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/) deals really well with these things.
otherwise I'm not sure if you can use it on IE8 but location.hash

Answer (score 0):

If you use window.location.hash it should work fine